# Eclipse icons not clear

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am launching an eclipse (photon) application to perform some activities.

[image]

My launched application works fine except the icon does not appear how they use to be on older version.

[image]

Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Is that an icon from one of your plug-ins? If yes, a common mistake is to forget to include it in `build.properties`. If no, does this issue also occurs with a new workspace and a new configuration area?

Comment: Yes. it is an icon from one of plug-ins.The red colored icon supposed to be a folder type. All other icons (in png) loaded but looks very tiny.